# Can i reuse the container exported to other class ? awilix package node js

Tags: node.js, express, awilix

I have been trying to implement the Awilix package for dependency injection in express js.
But the problem i am facing right now is,

All the modules are being registered properly in the "container.js", but the time i want to resolve in other classes to create an instance, error is thrown.

Container.js includes

```
const awilix = require('awilix');
const { Lifetime } = awilix;

const container = awilix.createContainer({
    injectionMode: awilix.InjectionMode.PROXY
});

const containerSetup = () => {

    container.loadModules([
        "./src/http/controllers/**/*.js"       //here the path is correct
    ],{
        formatName: "camelCase",
        resolverOptions: {
            lifetime: Lifetime.TRANSIENT,
            register: awilix.asClass
        }
    });
}


module.exports = {
    container,
    containerSetup
}
```

In route file,
dashboard.route.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { container } = require('../../../bootstrap/container');
const DashboardController = container.resolve('dashboardController');
```

Here the error is thrown, says, "AwilixResolutionError: Could not resolve 'dashboardController'."

Also, when i try to console.log(container.registrations) in the route file. 0 registration is shown. but shows the registered module in the container.js

So, what could be the problem? or what am i missing out here?